# 今更自分で突っ込まないでよ。追加料金払ってるんだからいいでしょう >>What does this mean in this context

Tags: meaning, translation, japanese-to-english, conversations, video-games

Context : MC is talking with a girl after he brought food to her place from a restaurant, where he is currently staying and working. The girl complains the food is a little bit cold, and suggests he hire Goppo (a transport lizard in the city) to deliver the meal faster.

G1: …少し冷めてるわね。もっと早く持ってこられないの

MC: 無理を言うなよ。これでも急いだんだぞ

G1:歩いてきたんでしょう。グオッポ使いなさいよ

MC: 料理宅配しながらあれに乗るのは無理じゃないか…

G1:要は慣れよ、慣れ

MC: 慣れかなぁ.
ってなんで俺、デリバリーなんてしてるんだ？？

G1:**今更自分で突っ込まないでよ。追加料金払ってるんだからいいでしょう** >>This part I don't understand .Please share your English translation

Comment: [Pure translation requests are off-topic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799). Please either explain why you were confused or at least add your translation attempt.

Comment: Yeah forgot that while typing ,I'm confuse about the first part "今更自分で突っ込まないでよ"

Comment: @4chanuser  Why is it confusing to you?

Answer (score 3):

The word 突っ込む has several meanings, spanning from literal to figurative, to everyday idiomatic. Literally it means to put into, to trust or to plunge. Figuratively, it can mean to poke your nose into another person's business or to poke fun at unreasonable things. Here it means something closer to "point out" or "talk about something negatively". A related word is the noun ツッコミ.

今更 means "now", "at this stage". The implication is it is too late for an action.

追加料金: extra fees

> 今更自分で突っ込まないでよ。追加料金払ってるんだからいいでしょう

roughly translates as

> Don't you think it is a little late to say those things (or pointing that out) now? I am paying extra, so it's fine, isn't it?

The girl is saying, "Hey what are you doing complaining now? I am paying extra, so don't complain."

Comment: Follow up question: Why didn't you translate「今更自分で突っ込まないでよ。」literally as "Don't point that out now, please!"? This sentence ends with「突っ込まないで」.

Comment: @JimmyYang Yes, literally it means that, as you say, but I think the tone of "突っ込まないでよ", coming from a young female is more playful, frisky or even coquettish rather than serious. In English "Please don't do that" sounds peremptory and serious.

Answer (score 0):

there is one guy answered me on a JP discord , and this maybe another translation meaning.I will post here so people can google later on ,in case some might be running into my problem with Japanese

> it's too late to quip about it now. I'm paying you extra, so it's fine, isn't it?'

突っ込む here refers to the boke/ tsukkomi routine: the boke is the one in the duo which says absurd things, and the tsukkomi the one who points out their absurdity with a quip. So, tsukkomi can refer to the quip itself, and tsukkomu to the act of saying the quip.